# Form validation custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have to make a custom directive for form validation.Such that all text inputs will be rendered by that directive. Directive should show validations errors as and when required.

**directive call:**

```
<ff-inputbox data-type="text" data-class="form-control" ng-model="newQuote.zipcode" data-name="zipcode" data-id="zipcode" data-placeholder="{{vocab.retrv_saveQuote.zip_lable}}" data-pattern="/^(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5})$/" data-required="required">
</ff-text>
```

**directive:**

```
app.directive('ffInputbox', [function ($parse) {
        return {
                     scope: {
              type : '@',
              class : '@',
              name : '@',
              id : '@',
              placeholder : '@',
              pattern : '@',
              required : '@'
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'modules/common/directives/ff-inputbox.tpl.html',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr){
              var ar = scope.formName;           
              var ar1 = scope.name;

            console.log(elem.$error);

            }
        };    
      }]);
```

**ff-inputbox.tpl.html**

```
<input type={{type}} class={{class}} name={{name}} id={{id}} placeholder={{placeholder}} ng-pattern={{pattern}} required={{required}} minLength="3"></input>
```

/////////////////////////////////
Now I m thinking to use ng-messages for which i require $error list. Accordingly i will show error msg on $touched ,$valid,$submitted conditions.
Is this a right approach?How will i fetch the $error list inside the link function? Or should a controller is required here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You need a form element with name attribute set and containing these fields inside. Then you can show the error message for invalid fields.

Second, Define a html template(like error-messages.tpl.html bellow) containing error codes with their messages. Then add this template for each field. It will show the message according to the type of error.

**error-messages.tpl.html**

```
<span ng-message="required" >This is mandatory</span>
<span ng-message="minLength" >Too Short</span>
<span ng-message="number" >Invalid number</span>
<span ng-message="date" >Invalid date</span>
<span ng-message="email" >Invalid email</span>
...
```

**Inject ngMessages to your module. As shown bellow**

```
angular.module('testModule',['ngRoute', 'ngResource', ..... , 'ngMessages'])
```

Now, In your template file `ff-inputbox.tpl.html`, You will need to add a message div with every input for showing error messages. *(considering the form name is testForm)*

```
<input type={{type}} class={{class}} name={{name}} id={{id}} placeholder={{placeholder}} ng-pattern={{pattern}} required={{required}} minLength="3"></input>

<div ng-messages="testForm[name].$error" ng-messages-include="error-messages.tpl.html" class="text-danger"></div>
```

This will show the error messages. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: thank you . Do i need to require ngMessages directive in my custom directive for this? and also how will ng-messages="testForm[name].$error" work? do i also need to pass form name as an attribute and then call it as {{formName}}[name].$error?

Comment: i tried using what you wrote but it's giving me an error: Controller 'ngMessages', required by directive 'ngMessagesInclude', can't be found!

Comment: @Isha You need to inject ngMessages to your module. I have updated the answer. Have a look.